# Error in Content Page on initializing FacebookClient

Tags: c#, facebook-c#-sdk

I am getting an error "Object Reference is not set to an Instance of an object" in the ContentPage of my MasterPage Facebook Application.

**Site.master.cs**

```
public FacebookSession CurrentSession
{
    get { return (new CanvasAuthorizer()).Session; }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        var auth = new CanvasAuthorizer { Perms = "email,read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access,user_about_me" };
        if (auth.Authorize())
        {
            ShowFacebookContent();
        }
}

private void ShowFacebookContent()
{
    var fb = new FacebookClient(this.CurrentSession.AccessToken);
    dynamic myInfo = fb.Get("me");
    lblName.Text = myInfo.name;
    imgProfile.ImageUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + myInfo.id + "/picture";
    lblBirthday.Text = myInfo.birthday;
    pnlHello.Visible = true;
}
```

This master Page works OK & displays UserName & ProfilePic.

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
SiteMaster myMasterPage;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myMasterPage = this.Page.Master as SiteMaster;
}
public void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var fb = new FacebookClient(this.myMasterPage.CurrentSession.AccessToken);

    dynamic feedparameters = new ExpandoObject();
    feedparameters.message = (message_txt.Text == null ? " " : message_txt.Text);
    feedparameters.user_message_prompt = "userPrompt";

    /*Dictionary<string, object> feedparameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    feedparameters.Add("message", "Testing Application");
    feedparameters.Add("user_message_prompt", "Post To Your Wall");
    feedparameters.Add("display", "iframe");*/

    dynamic result = fb.Post("me/feed", feedparameters);
}
```

Even this Page Loads OK but Problem comes when I try to Post using LinkButton.
Following Line gives the error.

**var fb = new FacebookClient(this.myMasterPage.CurrentSession.AccessToken);**

On LinkButton Click Object Reference is not set to an Instance of an object...

I will really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wel finally found what was the problem. Needed to add a hidden field.

```
<input type="hidden" name="signed_request" value="<%: Request.Params["signed_request"]%>"/>
```

I think this is neither mentioned any where in the documentation nor in the Provided Samples.